# Unable to find gl crate

Tags: rust

I'm following the instructions from [here](https://github.com/bjz/gl-rs). In the example folder, I use the [first](https://github.com/bjz/gl-rs/blob/master/examples/static_basic.rs) example. For some reason console says it can't find the external crate "gl". Here's what my Cargo.toml looks like.

```
[package]

name = "hello_world"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [ "bob <bobbuilder@gmail.com>" ]



[dependencies.gl]
git = "https://github.com/bjz/gl-rs"

[dependencies.glfw]
git = "https://github.com/bjz/glfw-rs.git"

[build-dependencies]
gl_generator = "*"

[dependencies]
gl_common = "*"

[[bin]]

name = "hello_world"
```

My build.rs

```
extern crate gl_generator;    // <-- this is your build dependency
extern crate khronos_api;    // included by gl_generator

use std::os;
use std::io::File;

fn main() {
let dest = Path::new(os::getenv("OUT_DIR").unwrap());

let mut file = File::create(&dest.join("gl_bindings.rs")).unwrap();

// This generates bindsings for OpenGL ES v3.1
gl_generator::generate_bindings(gl_generator::GlobalGenerator,
                                gl_generator::registry::Ns::Gles2,
                                khronos_api::GL_XML,
                                vec![],
                                "3.1", "core", &mut file).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: To be clear, you need the special features as indicated by "If you need a specific version of OpenGL, or you need a different API"? Otherwise, it looks like you could use the standard crate and skip the extra hassle.

Comment: It's also considered good citizenship to [note that you have cross-posted the question](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2thg0w/not_finding_crate_gl/) to other sources. (assuming that both instances are the same person!)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to says:

> Under the `[package]` section, add `build = "build.rs"`

But I don't see that in your `Cargo.toml`.